# Mochawesome Report add context

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js, mochawesome

I am using Mocha to run my test cases in a tool that I have built. To generate the report a use Mochawesome.

Now I need to add information to the HTML Report.

I have my test case:

```
describe('INTWL Response Pre Auth Flow network transaction and transactionID Validation', function () {
it('Step 1', async () => {
        responseMessage = await class.sendMessages(objectMessage)
})
})
```

Inside my `sendMessages` function i have imported the:

```
var addContext = require('mochawesome/addContext.js');
```

and inside then called `addContext` inside the method:

```
addContext(this, { title: 'This is my context title', value: objectMessage})
```

The information inside `objectMessage` is not printed in the HTML report generated.

I know that I am using arrow functions but I can't change that and I can't use the add context directly inside the test case.

Any solution?